# How to have a fixed timestep with interpolation and allow the player to switch game speed?

Tags: time, libgdx, game-physics

I'm making a game with libgdx and I've been using Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() for all of the physics but I've decided to implement the methods suggested [here](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) and [here](http://saltares.com/blog/games/fixing-your-timestep-in-libgdx-and-box2d/) for getting a fixed timestep with interpolation so the calculations can be more accurate.

I'd like for the player to be able to toggle the game speed so it's doubled or even quadrupled, but I'm not sure what's the correct way to go about doing it. Is it as simple as multiplying the step size in the last example of the second article? Or do I need to multiply the deltatime?

Comment: Assuming you did it basically the same way, I think it's as simple as scaling the value of deltaTime before adding it to `accumulator` and using it for interpolating frames.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! So if I'm understanding this correctly, if I double the `deltaTime` then the game will just take twice as many steps in the same frame rather than taking one step that's twice the size like I was previously doing for changing the speed. That's a lot better, thank you.

Comment: Yep. You do need to be sure your simulation can run fast enough to process the extra physics steps per render.